# Always execute copy-dependencies after updating dependencies in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp, m2e

I am using the maven eclipse plugin to manage dependecies of my web application project (eclipse WTP).
When I changed the dependencies I usually execute the copy-dependencies goal of maven to copy the project jars to the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder. Is there a way to have this done automatically when I change the dependencies in the pom file?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so hopefully by this point you are using the Eclipse m2e plugin. The m2e-wtp connector will add the dependencies declared in your pom.xml to the classpath when you run a server in Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing is: Maven is not a dependency management tool it's a build tools which holds the complete build information and NOT only the dependencies. Furthermore you should change your layout based to the conventions of Maven (src/main/java, src/test/java and src/main/webapp). Furthermore you should import your project into Eclipse as a Maven project afterwards it shouldn't be necessary to copy the dependencies to the WEB-INF/lib folder cause it should work out of the box.